# Python Polish character encoding issues

Tags: python, character-encoding

I'm having some issues with character encoding, and in this special case with Polish characters.

I need to replace all none windows-1252 characters with a windows-1252 equivalent. I had this working until I needed to work with Polish characters. How can I replace these characters?

The `é` for example is a windows-1252 character and must stay this way. But the `ł` is not a windows-1252 character and must be replaced with its equivalent (or stripped if it hasn't a equivalent).

I tried this:

```
import unicodedata

text = "Racławicka Rógé"
tmp = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', text).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
print(tmp.decode("utf-8"))
```

This prints:

```
Racawicka Roge
```

But now the `ó` and `é` are both encoded to `o` and `e`.

How can I get this right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to move to `1252`, that's what you should tell `encode` and `decode`:

```
>>> text = "Racławicka Rógé"
>>> text.encode('1252', 'ignore').decode('1252')
'Racawicka Rógé'
```

Comment: What was I thinking... Thank you very much! This did exactly what I needed! Probably thinking to difficult!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not handling with big texts, just like your example, you can make use of [Unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/0.04.16) library with the solution provided by [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe).

```
from unidecode import unidecode

text = u'Racławicka Rógé'
result = ''

for i in text:
    try:
        result += i.encode('1252').decode('1252')
    except (UnicodeEncodeError, UnicodeDecodeError):
        result += unidecode(i)

print result # which will be 'Raclawicka Rógé'
```